# AJAX post not working, data does not seem to be passing through

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

My AJAX post form doesn't seem to be working. It seems as if no data is being passed through. Any idea why?

**Form**

```
<label for="title">Please give your idea a title</label>
<br />
<input type="text" id="title" name="title" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="message">Please provide details of your idea</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="message" name="message" />
</p>
<input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Post"></input>
```

**jQuery**

```
  $.post("assets/post.php", {
      title: $("#title").val(),
      message: $("#message").val()
  }, function (data) {
      alert(data);
      $chat.prepend('<span class="idea"><strong style="color: #0081C5">' + $messageTitle.val() + '</strong>' + '&nbsp;-&nbsp;' + $messageBox.val() + '&nbsp;' + '<a class="delete" href="#">[Delete]</a>' + '</span>')
      $messageTitle.val('');
      $messageBox.val('');
      $('#post_confirm').show().html('<br><span class="confirm_msg">Message posted successfully</span>');
      $('#chat').height($(window).height() - $('.header').height() - $('.user').height());
      setTimeout(function () {
          $('#post_confirm').fadeOut('slow');
          $('#chat').height($chatHeight_user);
      }, 1000);
  });
```

**post.php**

```
<?php include("config.php"); 
$title = $_POST["title"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO idea (title,message) VALUES (:title,:message)";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':title'=>$title,':message'=>$message));
?>
```

I get the following error message:

[image]

Comment: Code looks okay, time for step-by-step debugging: (1) Is there any JavaScript error on page? Firefox's Firebug > Console > Errors can help (2) Is the ajax call being fired? Firefox's Firebug > Net > XHR can help (3) Is the data being received by the said PHP file? Do a [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)/[`print_r`](http://in2.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) and confirm from Firebug (4) Is the SQL query being formed properly? Echo `$q` to see, and execute manually in PHPMyAdmin... Pinpoint and provide feedback, so that solution can be found.

Comment: Please point out the content of post.php and specifically line 9, the one before and the one after. It seems that the PDOStatement function is called and forced to be a string, which it does not provide without a php __toString function.

Comment: @Gerben - managed to figure it out thanks. Turns out I was referring to a column that doesn't exist

Comment: @methuselah - You seem to have some trouble debugging the developed code in general. Maybe you could benefit from using an error handler so you know what is going on, instead of having to rely on feedback through a ajax query? Try to include this file at the root of your application: https://gist.github.com/hyperized/cc6a40573c2994380868 adjust the email adres on line 21 and your application will be reporting all the errors to your mailbox directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lack any trigger to start this post action.

```
$('#sendmessage').on('click', function(event)
{
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax(
    {
      url: "demo_test.txt",
      data: yourdatahere,
      success:function(result)
      {
        successevents here
      }
    });
});
```

It now listens to the ID of sendmessage for clicks. If its clicked it disables the default button behavior and processes your AJAX call instead.

Comment: It's a valid answer, but one really has to hope that the OP didn't forget the event handler after creating a button and writing a somewhat complex ajax call ?

Comment: Indeed a little more seems to be lacking here, I would like to see OP use [Gopal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912593/ajax-post-not-working-data-does-not-seem-to-be-passing-through/17912663?noredirect=1#comment26167801_17912593)s comment in conjunction with mine to solve his problem.